# 7zip program infected with malwares and viruses

Tags: windows, virus, malware, 7-zip, tar

## 7zip program infected with malwares and viruses.

#### [`Virus Total`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/b055fee85472921575071464a97a79540e489c1c3a14b9bdfbdbab60e17f36e4/relations) scanned the installer as good with malicious and suspecious relations.

**The [`7-zip`](https://www.7-zip.org/) program**

- [`7-zip v22.01 - (may be infected)`](https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe)

**From the `Virus Total` scan result**

> **Execution Parents(541) - the files will be created by the program when tested in sandbox**
>
> - [`YJSUBH.exe`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03b611fe30772104a842e8f27ba1b10a3de1bbc5158b93fec2272589bf075315)
> - [`Book1.xlsm`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/03608b026b19daee0b0bcba3a0574ba730fabea00221f3491d6cd253b52a8cf3) ...
>
> **PE Resource Parents(3) - resource files which will be created by the program**
>
> - [`dbad03d75774f6b6979fea765f57a4f12fc4d240db07ccc47b361ddb17f1a000`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/0f5475fd7d2eb511ee9407c2c9b10adf4a29ea58d17a5fa1c4d6905ca66922de)
> - [`Synaptics.exe`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/49ed3a3b30a39a9872486ec1f1a777277b51c8962bd30336389af04627f2bdc0) ...
>
> and all others

[`Synaptics.exe`](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/49ed3a3b30a39a9872486ec1f1a777277b51c8962bd30336389af04627f2bdc0) is malicious especially because it may used up cpu/disk resources.
I want to use `tar.gz` file format to compress/decompress files. I am using `7-zip` to use `tar.gz`.
Is the `7-zip` safe to use or it may infect with malwares to use up CPU resources? If it is malicious, then what are the alternatives to the `7-zip`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please change the formatting so your question and whatever you quoted from elsewhere is can be told apart. Why did you even test that [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) is carrying malware? 7-zip is reputable software that is clean.

Comment: Where did you download it from?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio : I downloaded from [7-zip website](https://www.7-zip.org/) today.

Comment: @DanielB : I edited.

Comment: That's the official website. It should be OK.

Comment: @RuddyLutonadio : OK. I was checking the program for `tar.gz` files.

Comment: What is the actual *real* problem here? We are not an "is my favourite software infected with malware?" site and your question should have a purpose beyond advertising that you might have a false positive. If you believe it is a false positive then the author of the software would be interested. The final line "what alternatives" would make your question off topic here as a product or shopping request.

Comment: @smithjohn - Just because another Portable Executable (PE) calls 7-zip is not relevant in determining if 7-zip is actually safe.  If you have any concerns, avoiding using 7-zip., is an acceptable solution The alternatives to 7-zip, is the built-in feature contained within Windows, questions seeking software recommendations of course are out of scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

7-Zip is software of good reputation and doesn't contain any malware.

But you have to be careful were you obtained your copy from.
If you downloaded it directly from the original makers (https://www.7-zip.org) it should be fine.

If you got it anywhere else all bets are off. There is no telling what others have added to the installer.
(This is actually true for any software. You just can't trust anything downloaded from random download sites. Always get it straight from the original maker or from a reputable app-store.)

So just download a fresh copy from https://www.7-zip.org and you should be fine.

I just downloaded a fresh copy myself and ran it through VirusTotal as well. Nothing to see there. It is clear.
(The items you are worried about in your post are totally normal for a VirusTotal scan. They are NOT indicative of a virus AT ALL.)

Comment: The scan result is good. It also indicate that [the file](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/b055fee85472921575071464a97a79540e489c1c3a14b9bdfbdbab60e17f36e4/relations)  `Execution Parents`, `PE Resource Parents `, and `Contacted IP Addresses` contains suspecious or malicious IP addresses, resource files, and files will be created by installation. I am asking if it is safe from the result.

Comment: @smithjohn Some known piece of malware calling 7-zip doesn't mean 7-zip itself is bad. There are many examples of utility-software like 7-Zip that give similar (or worse) results. WinZip and WinRar give a similar result. That is totally to be expected. Don't over-think it: In general: If the "Detection" page of VirusTotal calls it clean it is 99.999% sure to be clean. The other pages with information in VirusTotal provide a lot of technical detail, but you have to be very careful on how you interpret them. It is easy to get scared by a total non-issue. when you go delving too deep.